# Angular, Object oriented factory management

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to mix in a bit of oop to angular to solve a problem I have. So I basically want a list of "module" objects that are instantiated, then edited in the .config phase, and are able to be referenced easily. So, so far, I have this.

```
 .factory('moduleOb', function(){

    return function(name, cb) {
        this.name = name;
        this.callback = cb;
        this.currentState = "";
        this.states = {};
        this.addState = function(state, values) {

        };
    }   
})
```

So I want to be able to instantiate a few of these "modules" then I have a provider that has an addState return, wherein the config I would define the states which would push into the object, so like :

```
 .provider("routeTest", function() {

    return { 
        addState: function(state, values) {
            //push state[value] in this
        },
        $get: function $get() {
            return this;
        }
    }
})
```

(that's the idea anyways). So the intended goal would be to, in the config, let the user define states like

```
    .config(function(routeTestProvider){
    routeTestProvider
    .addState("mod1", ["n", "m"])
    .addState("mod2", ["r","j"]);
```

And those states would push/extend into their respective modules. Now where I am struggling is setting this "Array" (Could be something else?) of module objects and being able to reference the correct one. Maybe the better idea is to just have addState a function of the object, but how would I access it for .config if the object is a factory?

This provider/factory is in a main app, and all the modules using it would be entirely separate modules that were injected. So I'm trying to sort of track the modules as one module objects, and update the states therein.

I need some help wrapping my head around this to approach this correctly. Thank you for your time!

Comment: What are your specific question(s)?

Comment: @charlietfl how to set this up so I can have all the modules create their own module object and push in their state (hopefully with config but i'm not sure config will work, so maybe .run)